# Pandas resample time series in equal parts

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, finance, resampling

I am trying to resample a pandas time series in **N** equal parts.

My time serie has size **10**:

```
rng = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=10,freq='T')
ts=pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)

print(ts)
2013-01-01 00:00:00   -1.346024
2013-01-01 00:01:00    0.671637
2013-01-01 00:02:00    0.435566
2013-01-01 00:03:00    1.043379
2013-01-01 00:04:00    0.877782
2013-01-01 00:05:00   -1.216598
2013-01-01 00:06:00    0.801525
2013-01-01 00:07:00    1.041827
2013-01-01 00:08:00   -0.309048
2013-01-01 00:09:00    0.212750
Freq: T, dtype: float64
```

**How can I resample in N equal parts, N being > 10**

I expect the answer to have some of course some NaN.

I expect something looking like (N=12):

```
2013-01-01 00:00:00   -1.346024
2013-01-01 00:00:50    0.671637
2013-01-01 00:01:40    0.435566
2013-01-01 00:02:30    1.043379
2013-01-01 00:03:20    0.877782
2013-01-01 00:04:10         NaN
2013-01-01 00:05:00   -1.216598
2013-01-01 00:05:50    0.801525
2013-01-01 00:06:40    1.041827
2013-01-01 00:07:30   -0.309048
2013-01-01 00:08:20    0.212750
2013-01-01 00:09:10         NaN
Freq: 50S, dtype: float64
```

Note: the following code does work for N<10:

```
length = 9
timeSpan = (ts.index[-1]-ts.index[0]+timedelta(minutes=1))
rule = int(timeSpan.total_seconds()/length)
tsNew=ts.resample(str(rule)+"S")

print(tsNew)
2013-01-01 00:00:00   -0.337194
2013-01-01 00:01:06    0.435566
2013-01-01 00:02:12    1.043379
2013-01-01 00:03:18    0.877782
2013-01-01 00:04:24   -1.216598
2013-01-01 00:05:30    0.801525
2013-01-01 00:06:36    1.041827
2013-01-01 00:07:42   -0.309048
2013-01-01 00:08:48    0.212750
Freq: 66S, dtype: float64
```

Note: If possible, I would the answer still be compatible with multicolumn timeseries (such as Open/High/Low/Close financial series)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The resample method should use both fill_method='pad' and closed='right'

```
tsNew=ts.resample(str(rule)+"S", fill_method='pad',closed='right')

ts
2013-01-01 00:00:00   -1.827784
2013-01-01 00:01:00   -2.181001
2013-01-01 00:02:00   -2.498234
2013-01-01 00:03:00   -0.646579
2013-01-01 00:04:00   -0.720016
2013-01-01 00:05:00    1.298624
2013-01-01 00:06:00   -0.785790
2013-01-01 00:07:00    0.769829
2013-01-01 00:08:00   -0.877086
2013-01-01 00:09:00   -0.311500
Freq: T, dtype: float64

tsNew (for N=12)
2013-01-01 00:00:00   -1.827784
2013-01-01 00:00:50   -1.827784
2013-01-01 00:01:40   -2.181001
2013-01-01 00:02:30   -2.498234
2013-01-01 00:03:20   -0.646579
2013-01-01 00:04:10   -0.720016
2013-01-01 00:05:00    1.298624
2013-01-01 00:05:50    1.298624
2013-01-01 00:06:40   -0.785790
2013-01-01 00:07:30    0.769829
2013-01-01 00:08:20   -0.877086
2013-01-01 00:09:10   -0.311500
Freq: 50S, dtype: float64
```